# Python - Associate two list of points based on distance

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, geometry

I have two sets of n points, as Numpy arrays, in random order. I have to associate points between the two lists based on distance (L2) so that each point in list1 gets one and only corresponding point, the closest from list2.

My question: What's the quickest way to do it in terms of computation time?

For now, I compute the symmetric cross-norm matrix (with *scipy.spatial.distance_matrix*) and I sort points from there by looping for finding the lowest norm in the entire matrix. Then remove corresponding rows and columns and iterate until matrix is empty. I wonder if there's a known quicker way to do it.

[EDIT]: Here's the code and the example I get

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

rng = np.random.default_rng()
lst1 = rng.random((10, 2))
lst2 = lst1 + 0.1 * rng.standard_normal(lst1.shape)  # rng.random((10, 2))

mask = np.zeros((len(lst1), len(lst2)), dtype=bool)
dst = ma.array(distance_matrix(lst1, lst2), mask=mask)

ord_lst1 = []
ord_lst2 = []
for i in range(min(len(lst1), len(lst2))):
    index = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(dst), shape=dst.shape)
    ord_lst1.append(lst1[index[0], :])
    ord_lst2.append(lst2[index[1], :])

    dst[index[0], :] = ma.masked
    dst[:, index[1]] = ma.masked

fig = plt.figure()
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(x=lst1[:, 0], y=lst1[:, 1], label="list1")
plt.scatter(x=lst2[:, 0], y=lst2[:, 1], label="list2")
for p1, p2 in zip(ord_lst1, ord_lst2):
    plt.plot((p1[0], p2[0]), (p1[1], p2[1]), "--", color="black")
plt.legend()
```

The output is the following:
[image: Desired output]

As you can see, the huge association in the middle between two very spaced points can be troubling. However, the point of list1 in (0.4, 0.6) has its closest match with the upper-right list2, therefore making an association and ruling out those two points from further association.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please add some data

Comment: What if some point from list2 is the closest one for some list1 points? (Your picture doesn't show such ambiguous cases). Seems in this case you need some kind of weighted matching.

Comment: @DaniMesejo: data here was generated using:
rng = np.random.default_rng()
lst1 = rng.random((10, 2))
lst2 = lst1 + 0.03 * rng.standard_normal(lst1.shape)

Comment: @MBo: As I seek a 1-to-1 association table, for a given point in list1, the closest point in list2 shall be associated to it, therefore making association of those points impossible with others. It's as if we associate first the closest and them get them out of the association process.

Comment: list1: [1,0],[0,0]  list2: [0,1], [1,2]. If we walk list1 left-to right, we have 0-1, 1-0 index correspondence, if we walk right-to-left, we have 0-0, 1-1 corespondence (looks more intuitive)

Comment: @Maltergate Do you need traversal-order independent associations? This may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into scipy.spatial.KDTree
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html

Build the kdTree from list 2, and query it at each point in list 1

The following snippet is not tested so may need debugging. It should be a start for your own design

```
#L1 is numpy array with shape (N,2)
#L2 is numpy array with shape (N,2)
import scipy.spatial
tree=scipy.spatial.KDTree(L2)
assoc=[]
for I1,point in enumerate(L1):
    _,I2 = tree.query(point,k=1)
    assoc.append((I1,I2))
```

The `assoc` variable contains the final associations as a list of tuples of indices

EDIT: To help with the non-unique associations problem, **one first step may be to run the KDtree algorithm twice, once with "primary list" L1 and once with "primary list" L2, then retain only the associations common between the two.** You can then handle the remaining points as a special case.

Comment: What happens if two points from list1 get the same result in list2?

Comment: This answer is really neat. I didn't know about KDTrees. However, as pointed out @Stef, it doesn't guarantee the exclusivity. It also doesn't guarantee that it's the closest match. As we loop over points in L1 to find the closest point in L2, it will give an association between this L1 point and its closest L2 points, but there's no guarantee that there's not another L1 point closer to this L2 point, which would invalidate this association.

Comment: It may end up being slower, but you can record each point that was previously matched and then query more points when the nearest point is already taken. To query for more than one neighbor, you can change the value of `k` in the `query` function call. This will return a list of `k` nearest neighbors. You need to loop through these results to exclude already "taken" neighbors. This solves the case @Stef mentions, but is biased based on the order L1 is traversed.  If you want to minimize bias based on order, you can randomize your traversal of L1.

Comment: If you post your original python implementation, it may be possible to find ways to speed up your code without changing your algorithm. Some python and NumPy methods are known to be slower than others

Comment: @MichaelSohnen: Yes you're right. I've modified my question.

Comment: @Maltergate looking at your original implementation, it seems as though you are doing a brute-force approach, totalling at least N^2 comparisons for lists of length N. This is because np.argmin traverses the whole list in order to find the argument of the minimum. **One first step may be to run the KDtree algorithm twice, once with "primary list" L1 and once with "primary list" L2, then retain only the associations common between the two.** You can then handle the remaining points as a special case.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen: I'd suggest you tu update your answer with your last comment, just validated it. Thanks for the hand!

Comment: @Maltergate Will do. Thanks for validating it!